# Support library (v4 vs v13)

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm new in Android development and I'm considering if I have to use the support libraries or not.
The min SDK is 16 and target SDK is 22.

[On Android docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html), there is a note that is a a bit confusing to me, that is

> Note: If you are including the v4 support and v7 appcompat libraries in your application, you should specify a minimum SDK version of "7" (and not "4"). The highest support library level you include in your application determines the lowest API version in which it can operate.

So if my min sdk is 16, is using support library (v4 or v13) necessary?

Or have I to use it if I want a Lollipop feature for example on Jelly Bean api 16 (via v13 support libraries)?

Comment: Its not necessary to specify a minimum SDK version of "7"  in your project. Its for reference that these libraries are compatible to this version.

Comment: You use them if you need the features in them. Do you need RecyclerView? AppCompat? CardView? Then you need support  v7. Do you need fragments and fragment transactions which are compatible with earlier version of Android? Notifications? ActionBar? Then you need support v4. If you don't need any of these, you don't **have to** have them.

Comment: Have a look @ https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html as well to see which features they allow you to have and if you think you'd use them or not. Start without them and add them later if you need them if you're unsure.

Comment: @kha - That would make a good answer.

Comment: @BSMP Sure. added as an answer instead.

Comment: usually, to get any new features without targeting only the latest sdk version, you need the support library. For example, it contains now a few nice material stuff (cards, FABs, tints, snackbars...)

Comment: This is the most well written explanation I've read to date: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use them if you need the features in them.

Do you need RecyclerView? AppCompat? CardView? Then you need support v7.

Do you need fragments and fragment transactions which are compatible with earlier version of Android? Notifications? ActionBar? Then you need support v4.

If you don't need any of these, you don't have to have them.

Have a look at [developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html)
 to see which feature set they allow you to have and if you think you'd use them or not. Start without them and add them later if you need them if you're unsure.

With regards to versioning, they need a minimum version to work. If your minimum targeted version is less than their minimum required version, you should be able to use them without any problem.